# Why printing some inbuilt methods return VALUES while some NONE?

Tags: python, methods, return, nonetype

I am trying to understand the differences in output between the following code snippets:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(arr.sort()) // Output: None
print(arr.pop()) // Output: 5
```

In the first snippet, I understand that `arr.sort()` is called and it sorts the list in place. However, when I try to print the sorted list, it outputs `None`. In the second snippet, I understand that `arr.pop()` is called to remove and return the last element of the list, which is `5`.

Can someone please explain to me why the first snippet outputs `None` instead of the sorted list, and confirm my understanding of the second snippet's output?

Answer (score 0):

The `list.sort` method changes the value of the list *inplace* and return the value `None`. In other words, contrarily to methods that return the value of interest, you don't use this method by assigning its result to a variable. Instead, it changes the list itself. It's not visible in your case because the list is already sorted but if you use an unsorted list:

```
arr = [5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
print(arr.sort()) // Output: None
print(arr) // Output: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

You can notice that the list was changed even though the method was called within a `print` (this can lead to hard-to-find bug sometimes).

The `list.pop` method is different as it changes the list inplace (removing the item present at the given index) AND returns this item - in your case 5. Hence `print(arr.pop())` print 5.